# Scrape without tag in <a>

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape with python a site but i have a problem with text in  tag without class or id

```
<div class="d-inline"> <img class="team-img" src="https://cdn.fifacm.com/content/media/imgs/fifa22/teams/52/l73.png?v=10"> <a href="/22/team/73/paris-saint-germain"> Paris Saint-Germain </a> </div>
```

I need to extract "Paris Saint-Germain"

How could I do?

Thanks
Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tag = """
<div class="d-inline">
 <img class="team-img" src="https://cdn.fifacm.com/content/media/imgs/fifa22/teams/52/l73.png?v=10"/>
 <a href="/22/team/73/paris-saint-germain">
  Paris Saint-Germain
 </a>
</div>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(tag, 'html.parser')


tag= soup.select_one('div.d-inline')
print(tag.text)
```

Output:

```
Paris Saint-Germain
```